# Find the width of a triangle at a certain point

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Is there a way to find the width of a triangle at a certain point? I'm not very good at maths so I don't know many maths words, so I'm going to explain it in a diagram.
[Is there any way to find the length of p?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umZBo.png)

[image]

Comment: What is $z{}{}$?

Comment: Smells like length scale factor.

Comment: Hi, so we're looking for $p$ and trying to use at least variables as possible?

Comment: im trying to find p using the labelled lines and possibly some angles, but I didnt think it was needed so I didnt mark the angles.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know $p$ is to know the overall height from the base that is not $x$ or $y$ up to the tip. Using that, $x$, $z$, $y$ you could find $p$, otherwise it's impossible. Also next time provide angles and measurements because there is a lot of assumptions banking on this. :)

Comment: oh ok thanks :3

Comment: i changed the diagram

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x,y,$ and $z$ are **fixed** values.  As the (presumably acute) angle between sides $x$ and $y$ increases, $p$ will increase.  Therefore, there is insufficient information to determine $p$.